# How to use the TYPE command in a batch file to output only a part of the line

Tags: batch-file, types, findstr

I have a batch file that outputs only a few lines from a log file. The command I'm using is the following:

```
TYPE "file.log" | FINDSTR /C:"CPU usage:" /C:"RAM:" | FINDSTR /v /c:"Total: 0 B/s" >> "temp.log"
```

I'm trying to speed up this command and reduce the size on the output file. To achieve that, I would like to output only a part of the line. A typical line looks like:

```
2   2015-01-20 18:07:16.808 INFO    somelongtext1   text2   shorttext3  Physical RAM: Total=8000 MB
3   2015-01-20 18:07:16.886 INFO    text5   shorttext2  text6       Total CPU usage: 42.87%
```

Is there a way to output the line without the text1, text2, textX.... ?

The second FINDSTR makes sure I don't output line with value "0".

The columns do not have a fixed length however the text I want to get ride of is almost always the same (3-4 different words).

My files have about 100000 lines and I will output about 10000 only

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you've got a useless use of `TYPE`.  `findstr` is capable of reading text files.  Your command can be made a bit more efficient by getting rid of `TYPE`.  You can also gain some efficiency by replacing your `findstr /v` with internal substring substitution.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>"temp.log" (
    (
        for /f "tokens=1-4,7*" %%I in (
            'findstr /c:"CPU usage:" /c:"RAM:" "file.log"'
        ) do (
            set "line=%%I %%J %%K %%L %%N"
            if "!line!"=="!line: 0 B/s=!" (
                echo(!line!
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It's more code, but internal commands are usually faster than executables.  The initial `findstr` will help if you're parsing large files, though.  Text stream processors are faster than `for` loops.

It looks like your log you're scraping always needs columns 5, 6, and 7 removed.  If that's the case, you can simply include a `tokens` argument in your `for /f` loop and keep columns 1 through 4, then everything after 7.  (Skipping `%%M` was intentional in the code above.)

Comment: thanks! I added more details to my question, the columns don't have a fixed length but I know their content (3-4 possibilities)

Comment: @remyremy Skipping tokens I think will be faster than removing static strings.  If this doesn't work for you, you can try something like `for %%x in (text1 text2 text3) do set "line=!line:%%x=!"` to remove what you don't want.  Or you can just do a series of `set "line=!line:shortstring=!"` and `set "line=!line:somelongtext1=!"` before the `echo(!line!`.

Comment: it works fine but it's a bit slower than before. Could you explain what the two line mean: `if "!line!"=="!line: 0 B/s=!" (              echo(!line!`

Comment: You also weren't removing columns before.  cmd performs substring substitutions via `%variable:search=replace%`.  The `!` simply indicate delayed expansion.  So `!line: 0B/s=!` is `!line!` with `0B/s` replaced with nothing if present.  Therefore, if *x1==x2*, then the variable did not contain `0B/s`.  The `if` statement is true, and the `echo` fires.  Using a `echo(` prevents problems potentially caused by lines beginning with `/?`.